# Flutter: copyWith Constructor Not Working Properly

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter I have the following class:

```html
class ContainerCardData {
  ContainerCardData({
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.elevation = 4,
    this.gradientColors = const [Colors.blue],
    LinearGradient? gradient,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
    this.child,
  })  : borderRadius = borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(10),
// getDefaultGradient is a function that returns a gradient (which is perfectly valid)
        gradient = gradient ?? getDefaultGradient(gradientColors);
```

I pass values to the constructor with this **copyWith** method:

```html
ContainerCardData copyWith({
    double? width,
    double? height,
    double? elevation,
    List<Color>? gradientColors,
    LinearGradient? gradient,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
    Widget? child,
  }) =>
      ContainerCardData(
        width: width ?? this.width,
        height: height ?? this.height,
        elevation: elevation ?? this.elevation,
        gradientColors: gradientColors ?? this.gradientColors,
        gradient: gradient ?? this.gradient,
        borderRadius: borderRadius ?? this.borderRadius,
        child: child ?? this.child,
      );
```

**My problem** is that no matter what values I pass for `gradientColors`, the `getDefaultGradient` always receives the default value (Colors.blue in this instance)

How is that possible, when I pass valid values to it.

Also, when I print:

```html
final containerCardData = ContainerCardData(
      gradientColors: [Colors.orange],
      height: 92,
      elevation: 4,
      borderRadius: tileBorder,
    );
    
  final x = containerCardData.copyWith(
    gradientColors: [Colors.green],
  );
  
  // x.gradientColors -> The values I passed
  // x.gradient -> the default colors!
  print(
    '1) ${containerCardData.gradientColors} => ${containerCardData.gradient?.colors}');
  print('2) ${x.gradientColors} => ${x.gradient?.colors}');
```

**Output**

```
flutter: 1) [MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3))] => [MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3)), Color(0xff4dabf5)]

flutter: 2) [MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff4caf50))] => [MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3)), Color(0xff4dabf5)]
```

**Why is the gradient always using the default `gradientColors`?**

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of your code? Print `gradientColors` and `gradient?.colors` both for `containerCardData` and `x`.

Comment: @enzo Added the output

Comment: Ok, but why aren't the colors passed to it? I'm a bit confused

Comment: The logic for `copyWith` is that if `gradient` is not specified as an argument, `copyWith` will reuse whatever `this.gradient` *already is*.  Calling `copyWith` with a new value of `gradientColors` will not change the value of `this.gradient` and therefore will not change the value of `gradient` in the copy.

Comment: @jamesdlin Wait, that makes sense! The first time I called the constructor before making a copy, a gradient was set, and then on the second time when I used 'copyWith' the gradient already has a value, and therefore the ?? getDefaultGradient wasn't called! Let me test this to confirm!

Answer (score 1):

copyWith() is used to override assigned values with new.

What that means is if you have x with A=1,B=1,C=1 as constructed by default, and want x with A=1,B=2,C=1. you can copWith(B=2) and achieve that.

Your implementation of the override is also asserting that, but you aren’t  passing new values to gradient hence no overwrite.

So, if you do :

```
final x = containerCardData.copyWith(
    gradientColors: [Colors.green],
gradient: LinearGradient(
//pass new values
),
  );
```

should work!